# docker ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref

Tags: dockerfile

Docker build fails when I'm trying to copy files from a different location that I'm running the docker command from.

I am experiencing this error when running

```
docker build --build-arg FILES_LOCATION=/home/user/programs/tools/kafka-3.5.1-src -t kafka-container .
```

> failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref `3baae6f4-329d-42ac-972f-e9812699ed00::zauz386apf2jx71o4xckaacp2`: failed to walk `/var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount524500426/home/user/programs/tools: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3251433741/home/user/programs/tools`: no such file or directory

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine

# Set environment variable for specifying the location of files to copy
ARG FILES_LOCATION

WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from the specified location on the local machine to the container
COPY ${FILES_LOCATION} /app
```

Is it because the permissions of `/home/user` (inside of which the files to be copied are) are `drwxr-x---`?

I don't understand the context folder and how should I use it?

Comment: The answer is: don't use absolute paths